# ASP.NET MVC Editor Template; Positioning of columns for display

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using an editor template in my ASP.net MVC project.  The editor template consists of a hidden field, a check box, a label, and a text box.

Here is the editor template:

```
@model Models.Domain.myObject

<p>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id) 

    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DefaultCount, new { disabled = "disabled"})

</p>
```

Here is what I have in my view that uses this template:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myObject)
```

Sometimes it is possible that I have 3 myObjects and sometimes I have 10.  MVC does a nice job of setting all of these up for me with one exception.

I want the Names to all align right with each other and I want the check boxes to align left with each other for appearance purposes.

How can I do this?

Right now I'm getting something like this:

```
displaydisplay   checkbox textbox
display  checkbox textbox
displaydisplaydisplay checkbox text box
```

What I'm trying to get is (Hopefully you can see the alignment):

```
       displaydisplay   checkbox textbox
              display   checkbox textbox
displaydisplaydisplay   checkbox textbox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution is based on html/css. 
You can use "div" or "table".

Example using the table option:

**VIEW "MOTHER"**

```
<table>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.myObject)
</table>
```

**VIEW "Child"**

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 200px; text-align: right;">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Selected)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DefaultCount, new { disabled = "disabled"})
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Note:** as I said, you can use Divs to do the same visual efect and you can add "css classes" in order to have a cleaner code.